# JavaScript: Variable undefined inside if else

Tags: javascript, function, redirect, if-statement, arguments

Here I have a simple countdown function that redirects the user after 5 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timer = 5;
var counter = document.getElementById("countdown");

function countdown(target)
{
    counter.innerHTML = timer--;
    if (timer >= 0)
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
            countdown();
        }, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        // Redirect the user

        console.log(target); // Outputs "undefined" after 5 seconds

        if (!typeof target === "undefined")
        {
            window.location.href = target;
        }
    }
};

var target = "/account/";
countdown(target);

</script>
```

The problem is, when 5 seconds elapse and it's time for the `window.location.href` to do the redirection, the "target" variable is undefined, I'm not sure why this happens.

I have researched and tried various solutions, even setting the "target" the way "timer" and "counter" are set, but none worked. My goal is to set a different "target" at each function instance.

**UPDATE**: Setting `countdown();` to `countdown(target);` fixed the "undefined" issue, but the `window.location.href` object still doesn't redirect to the `target` variable value, What can be done to fix this?

Comment: What is `str` in the program?

Comment: Sorry, it is "target" instead, post updated.

Comment: You didn't pass any arguments to `countdown` in the `setTimeout` callback.

Comment: I have tried this approach, but it still doesn't work. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass target to countdown in setTimeout

```
function countdown(target)
{
    counter.innerHTML = timer--;
    if (timer >= 0)
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
            countdown(target);
        }, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        // Redirect the inactive user to the homepage

        console.log(target); // Outputs "undefined" after 5 seconds

        if (!typeof target === "undefined")
        {
            window.location.href = target;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I have accepted this as the answer because it solved the initial issue of "target" being "undefined" but I encourage reader to also check out my answer below (which solves the full issue) and upvote it if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, for some reason, the `if (!typeof target === "undefined")` still returned true even though `target` was indeed defined, which caused `window.location.href` to not fire up and redirect to the `target` value.

**UPDATE**: I was doing it the wrong way, it was a grouping issue, but using `if (typeof target !== "undefined")` makes it work as expected.

I'm sharing the fixed code in case it helps someone else:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var timer = 5;
var counter = document.getElementById("countdown");

function countdown(target)
{
    counter.innerHTML = timer--;
    if (timer >= 0)
    {
        setTimeout(
            function()
            { countdown(target); }, 1000
        );
    }
    else
    {
        // Redirect the user
        if (typeof target !== "undefined")
        {
            window.location.href = target;
        }
    }
};

var target = "/MixaPay/";
countdown(target);

</script>
```

Thanks everyone who have contributed.

Comment: [That expression didn't work because it's grouped as `(!(typeof target)) === "undefined"`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) Use `!==`.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I haven't thought doing that, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem, when you call the countdown function again, you should send the "target" object.

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        countdown(); // should be: countdown(target);
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Tried that one, it sets "target" to the correct value, but the redirect in the "else" still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this, its working, you forgot to pass the argument in your function.

```
var timer = 5;
var counter = document.getElementById("countdown");

function countdown(timer,target){

counter.innerHTML = timer--;
if (timer > 0)
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        countdown(timer,target);
    }, 1000);
}
else
{
    // Redirect the inactive user to the homepage

   console.log(target); // Outputs "undefined" after 5 seconds

    if (!typeof str === "undefined")
    {
        window.location.href = target;
    }
}
};

var target = "/account/";

countdown(timer,target);
```

Comment: Why have you added "timer" to the function arguments? Timer works that way and is decremented as expected. The problem is the "window.location.href" not redirecting to the "target" value.

Answer (score 0):

try using full url instead of using absolute url to redirect like instead of `/account/` use `localhost/account/`

**UPDATE**  This must work I have tested it

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
<script>

var timer = 5;
var counter = document.getElementById("countdown");

function countdown(target)
{
counter.innerHTML = timer--;
if (timer >= 0)
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        countdown(target);
    }, 1000);
}
else
{
    // Redirect the inactive user to the homepage

    console.log(target); // Outputs "undefined" after 5 seconds


        window.location.href = target;

}
};

var target = "/account/";
countdown(target);
</script>
```

Comment: Absolute URL is what you're suggesting me to use (full url) and currently I'm using what's called a Relative URL, and that's not the solution, check the answer I've posted.